# How to set a default image in an ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to add a default image to an **ionic** app. Currently I'm getting images inside the app through a link which is in the rows of the tables in the **database**. However if the image does not exist anymore or the link is broken I want the app to display a `default/fall-back` image and not this default ripped apart painting icon.

This is one of the methods I have tried getting it to work but it doesn't.

```
        <ion-card transparent class="detailView" *ngFor="let act of activities">
        <img class="img" src="{{act.image}}"
        onerror="this.src='assets/imgs/defualt.jpg';" alt = "Missing Image" />
```

**`{{act.image}}`** talks to the database, to be precise to the activity table in the database and extracts the image links. How do I implement a default option if the image can't be displayed?

A few extra tidbits; the app is written with **Ionic** Framework and implements the use of **Typescript**, **Sass** and **Angular**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

```
<img [src]="act.image" alt="Missing image" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='assets/imgs/default.jpg';" />
```

You’re using a locally saved file as default, so it’s unlikely to happen, but for good practice, clear “onerror” to avoid an endless loop in case the “fallback” image doesn’t exist.

Comment: Above my now default / placeholder image I still get this corrupted little image icon. How do I remove that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<ion-card transparent class="detailView" *ngFor="let act of activities">
  <img class="img" src="{{act.image}}"alt = "image" *ngIf="act.image" />
  <img class="img" src="assets/imgs/defualt.jpg"alt = "Missing Image" *ngIf="!act.image" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use img tag as describe in ionic and onError fallback

Ref : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

```html
<img [src]="img.imgsrc" onError="src = 'assets/imgs/user.png'">
```

Comment: I tried this but my code gets marked in a very weird way, making me think my editor is not seeing this as a link.

```
          <img class="img" src="{{act.image}}" onerror="src = 
           'http://www.jasminauburn.com.au/wp-content/themes/jasmine-family- 
           restaurent/images/noimage.png'"/>

```

Comment: In case of error, try to use local image url because this is faster. Use as it is written with lower and upper case `onError="src = 'assets/imgs/user.png'"`

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Angular Directive to load default image until image loads and when the image loads it gets rendered on the dom and if it fails to load the default image is shown.

You can use this directive as

```
<img
    class="item-img-thumbnail border"
    defaultImg
    src="{{ item.src }}"
    alt="..."
/>
```

Below is directive code `image-default.directive.ts` file.

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[defaultImg]'
})
export class ImageDefaultDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('src')
  @Input()
  src: string;

  _defaultImg: string;
  @Input()
  private set defaultImg(value: string) {
    this._defaultImg = value || 'assets/images/default.svg';
  }

  originalSrc: string;
  isOriginalImgLoaded = false;

  constructor() {}

  /**
   * @description it loads default image 1st and store original src to a variable
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.originalSrc = this.src || this._defaultImg;
    this.src = this._defaultImg;
  }

  /**
   * @desciption it is called when image is loading fails.
   * For 1st fail - default image, it loads original image
   * On 2nd fail - original image, it loads default image back.
   */
  @HostListener('error')
  onError() {
    if (!this.isOriginalImgLoaded) {
      this.src = this.originalSrc;
      this.isOriginalImgLoaded = true;
    } else {
      this.src = this._defaultImg;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @desciption it is called when image is loaded successfully.
   * 
   * 
   */
  @HostListener('load')
  onLoad() {
    if (!this.isOriginalImgLoaded) {
      this.src = this.originalSrc;
      this.isOriginalImgLoaded = true;
    }
  }
}
```

> NOTE: to change default image path replace `assets/images/default.svg` with your path in above code.